# ServiceNow's REST API data in Power BI

Tags: rest, powerbi, servicenow

Seeking advice on querying and storing ServiceNow's REST API data in Power BI, especially with Change Data Capture (CDC) tools for incremental updates. Any recommendations or shared experiences? Also, any helpful links, articles, blogs, or GitHub repositories to share?

I've attempted configuration in Azure Power BI, but I've hit a roadblock on how to store the live/incremental data. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.